# How can I see what functions I call from a c++ standard library?

Tags: c++, debugging, terminal, std

Let's say im using a c++ stl list and I declare it and do some operations with it. How would I see what specific functions inside the stl list template my program is calling. For example if I have this code:

```
 std::list<std::string> someList;
 someList = someOtherList;
```

How could I print exactly which constructor function within stl list the program calls?

Comment: You can't print it, but you could inspect it by stepping with a debugger. Edit : Maybe a good profiler could give you sample stack traces.

Comment: Also, that code should have a constructor call, a copy assignment call separately.

Comment: or grep symbols, if not inlined...

Comment: You could also create your own header overriding the stl one and see where the compiler complains

Comment: Looking at the assembly would tell you.  That said, this kind of sounds like an XY problem.  What are you trying to solve by knowing which constructor is called?

Comment: _"How could I print exactly which constructor function within stl list the program calls?"_ Well, you could deduce from the [reference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which constructors or other operators are called.

Comment: To answer the constructor part: the code you show calls the _default constructor_. We can see that from the code because there is no argument given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two answers to your question:

- You can't.
- You can still do it a little bit.

The c++ standard only defines what the STL is supposed to do, but not how. By definition it should be impossible for you to tell what happens from the outside.

Therefore, it is implementation defined what your library actually does. It could just create your list, or it could write a Java webserver for generating c++ lists, execute it and give you back the result. You couldn't tell the difference.

However, fear not. There still two possibilities to get some of the information you want. First, you can buy the c++ standard and look at the sample implementation of the STL. (Luckily you actually get most it at cppreference for free.) Or, you can use a debugger to step through the code while executing to see what functions are called.

Be aware though, the first answer was not just for giggles. You can run into serious problems with the debug approach. Some STL implementations do not care about readability. They use whatever ugly piece of c++ which is the fastest and thus might be very hard to understand. Moreover, some libraries only supply compiled binaries and header files thus no luck at viewing the code.

Nevertheless, try it. Maybe you get to know what you want. If not, you still learn by using the debugger properly. :D